# Entity Framework navigation properties based on a discriminator(type) column

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, navigation-properties

I have 3 entities

```
Provider
{
    ProviderId -PK
    Name
}

ProviderType1
{
    ProviderType1Id-PK
    Name
}

ProviderType2
{
    ProviderType2Id-PK
    Name
}
```

Then I have anothher entity called PreferredProvider  which is used as a mapper between Provider to set the preferred provider from either ProviderType1 or ProviderType2.It has columns like this.

```
PreferredProvider
{
    PreferredProviderId - PK
    ProviderId - FK Provider
    PrefProviderId - FK ProviderType1,ProviderType2 
    PrefProviderType - discriminator column to detect type of provider

    // navigation properties
    [ForeignKey("PrefProviderId")]
    ProviderType1 Prov1

     // navigation properties
    [ForeignKey("PrefProviderId")]
    ProviderType2 Prov2

}
```

So i am using the navigation property like this

```
GetDbSet<PreferredProvider>().Where(p => p.ProviderId == 4 && p.PrefProviderType == 'ProviderType1').Select(p => p.Prov1).ToList();
```

My question is when i am dealing with one type i.e ProviderType1(s) it's fine but how to combine when i have to get all the preferred providers for a provider containing ProviderType1(s) and ProviderType2(s).Actually i can get that using left join but want a better approach.Please help me.